# calling a function using this.value

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass the appropriate makeData function into the data element in ReactTable according to which year is selected. I keep getting a syntax error and I'm not sure why it won't let me compile it as is.

My logic is this:

The select value has an onChange function that will call handleChange whenever a different year is selected. Once handleChange is called, it will set the value to the event target.

The data object will then pass to the "data" element in ReactTable as "this.value"

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of stuff wrong here:

1. Functional components don't have `state`. Use a class that extends `React.Component` if you need state
2. `handleChange` can't be placed inside of the JSX. Again, use a class and make that a method of the class
3. `this.state.value` has the function in a string. You probably want `this.state = {value: makeData2014()};`. You do this in your JSX as well. Wrap the function call in curly braces instead of strings like so: `<option value={makeData2014()}>2014</option>`
4. When you call `setState`, you're updating `this.state.value`, not `this.value`. Thus, you don't need `this.value` at all and you should remove it.
5. To top it off, you didn't add the specific error message, so I can't even be sure this is all of it.

Step one should be fixing up all of these issues. After that, if you still have any problems, update your question with the new code and the specific error message you're getting.